# Woocommerce - Change product price when variant is selected instead of adding new element

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a bunch of variable products on Woocommerce. On the product page, when an option is selected by the user, instead of updating the product price, it automatically creates a new element on the page with the selected variant price.

Does anyone know how to go about making it change that one price above and stop it from creating another element on the page with the correct price. This confuses users (as they see two prices now).

[image]

Thank you very much !